# How to compile using uclibc?

Tags: configuration, buildroot, uclibc

Hi all I have installed buildroot toolchain and am able to compile simple "Hello World" program which runs on uClibc based chroot. However I am confused how to do so for programs that use ./configure as how to ask it to use the uclibc based toolchain and not the glibc based toolchain present in my system.
My OS is Fedora and it is i386 based machine.I want to compile programs using uClibc for the same platform.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

buildroot contains the package directory where there are numerous examples how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Just set CC=PATH_TO_BUILDROOT_UCLIBC_GCC etc.

And you don't need to use chroot:
`xxx/buildrootxxx/output/host/bin/xxxxx-gcc` works fine, it would search the headers and libs in its own directory (like `xxx/buildrootxxx/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi/sysroot/usr/*`)